# Add items in data object

Tags: object, extjs, model, store

Hello i am have data in this format:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "some title",
            "body": "some body",
            "coordinate": [
                {
                   "id": 1,
                    "x": 10,
                    "y": 20,
                    "z": 30
                },
                {
                   "id": 2,
                    "x": 30,
                    "y": 20,
                    "z": 30
                },
                {
                   "id": 3,
                    "x": 20,
                    "y": 30,
                    "z": 30
                },
                {
                   "id": 4,
                    "x": 50,
                    "y": 40,
                    "z": 20
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And have this data model:

```
Ext.define('Book.model.Shops', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [
        { name: 'id', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'title', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'body', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'coordinate', type: 'auto' },
    ]
})
```

I am want add new items in current record inside "coordinate" object, but i am don't know how do it.
 When add new record i'am make like this:

```
       newRec = {
                title: newTitle,
                body: newBody,
                };
            store.add(newRec)
```

But how to make adding items to the current record in the object "coordinate"&

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use has many model for this like that

Ext.define("Book.model.Cordinate", {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

```
        fields: [
            { name: 'id', type: 'int' },
            { name: 'y', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'y', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'z', type: 'string' }               
        ]

    });


    Ext.define('Book.model.Shops', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

        fields: [
            { name: 'id', type: 'int' },
            { name: 'title', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'body', type: 'string' }               
        ],
        hasMany: {model: 'Book.model.Cordinate', name: 'coordinate'}              
    });


 var shops = Ext.create('Book.model.Shops', {id: 1, title: 'some title'});

var coordinate = Ext.create('Book.model.Cordinate', {id: 1, y: 'test'});

var lcoordinate = shops.coordinate();

lcoordinate.add(coordinate);

Ext.Msg.alert(shops.get('title'));

Ext.Msg.alert(shops.coordinate().first().get('y'));
```

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.2/#!/api/Ext.data.association.HasMany

Comment: thanks, but this solution add 'coordinate' not in 'data' object of store, can insert 'coordinate' in 'data'?

Comment: @user3045654  I've updated the example , check it is work right now.

Comment: hi @user3045654 I'm share to you the example in fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ep24cc30/

Comment: Hi , @user3045654 , About your question , once you map "coordinate" as many collection extjs automatically know this is a store , when you call coordinate() is a store object there